# dockerfile-mode, suddenly weird indentation

Tags: emacs, config

I recently added dockerfile-mode to my Emacs config. Now in some files, whenever I press enter at the end of a line, 8 whitespaces are added to the front of that line. THis happens in Dockerfiles but also at least in a file .scratch I use as a general dump. I load dockerfile-mode like this:

```
(use-package dockerfile-mode
  :ensure t
  :mode ("Dockerfile\\'" . dockerfile-mode))
```

Does anybody have an idea if the problem may come from the way I load dockerfile-mode?

Comment: Does `*scratch*` end up in `dockerfile-mode`? If not then this is unrelated.

Comment: `*scratch*` stays as before loading `dockerfile-mode`. My `.scratch` file is also not in `dockerfile-mode`, it just has some sort of indentation enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `dockerfile-mode` doesn't make `indent-line-function` a local variable. So, in files like `.scratch` which I assume has no `major-mode` indent function defined, dockerfile's indent function would still mess things up.

I noticed there is an open [pull request](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-mode/pull/46) to fix it, but it is simple to fix yourself by just making the `indent-line-function` local in `dockerfile-mode`.

Comment: Thanks! That already helped and now it looks like the fix is in the latest update of `dockerfile-mode`.